# Conversion of DEM raster to ASCII format in ArcGIS10.4

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, raster-conversion

I have a DEM raster file in .tif format. I need to convert it to ASCII format. I used conversion tool in ArcGIS from raster to ASCII, but the result is in .txt instead of .asc. What should I do?
[image]

Comment: Did you specify the `.asc` extention in the Output ASCII raster file box? When you are choosing where to save the file, select type and then select the second `File` option. The output will be `.asc` instead of `.txt`.

Comment: The file suffix has *nothing* to do with file format. If it has the correct format and you want a different file name, rename it.

Comment: @MarceloVilla, By default its taking .TXT extension

Comment: @Vince, no its showing as text format, but i need it in asc format

Comment: @Namitha See my comment edit. Doing that changes the extension.

Comment: Is ASCII and ASCII grid format is same?

Comment: ASCII ***is*** text. There are an infinite number of formats and a finite number of three-character suffixes. Disable the  Windows security hole disguised as a feature that hides file suffixes and pay attention to the *content* of the file instead of the suffix.

Comment: This might not be your problem but I'd like to leave a note about ASCII DEM. If you have your system in your particular language (different than English) ArcGis might create an ASCII file with comma separation using comma (,). Non-mainstream software could have problems using that kind of ASCIIs
By my own experience, Scoops3D

Comment: The only work around is renaming output abc.txt to abc.asc using Windows explorer. Changing this in tool will result in abc.asc.txt.

Comment: What format do you expect when you say ".asc"? An Esri ASCII GRID, an X, Y, Z file or something else?

Comment: An ESRI ASCII Grid format